# Iteration vs Recursion efficiency

Tags: performance, recursion, stack, cpu

I got a basic idea of how recursion works - but I've always programmed iteratively.

When we look at the keywords CPU/stack/calls and space, how is recursion different from iterations?

It needs more memory because of running many "stacks(?)" which each (most likely) stores a value. It therefore takes up much more space, than an iterative solution to the same problem. This is generally speaking. There are some cases where Recursion would be better, such as programming Towers of Hanoi and such.

Am I all wrong? I've got an exam soon and I have to prepare a lot of subjects. Recursion is not my strong suit, so I would appreciate some help on this matter :)

Comment: If you program recursively the compiler might make it iterative for you anyway, but you have the benefit that you don't have think about how much space you'll use (because stack is a magical, unlimited resource!).  If you're handling the unknown space problem in iteration using piecewise allocations you'll likely waste just as much memory as with recursion and you'll probably have heap management CPU overhead too.  On the other hand, if the compiler doesn't fix it then recursion can result in a long chain of function returns to unwind the stack.

Comment: @sh1 The stack is most definitely not a "magical, unlimited resource". In fact, it is typically quite limited... Deep recursion is thus prone to "Stack overflow" errors, which generally abruptly terminate a program...

Comment: @twalberg I think if that wasn't self-evident then this site would have to be called something else.  I'm just having a laugh at the lack of error detection (outside of crashing) available for that technique.  That said, you can't detect errors with `malloc` either.  All memory is magical and unlimited so long as your program doesn't crash.

Comment: Sh1, if we imagine the compiler did not "make" it iterative, how/ exactly is recursion generally acting when it comes to CPU, stack, calls and/or space? 

Thanks for your comments - I just don't quite understand it.

Comment: @sh1 That mindset is sort of like "there's unlimited money in my bank, at least until Vito stops by with his Louisville Slugger"... Memory is not magical, nor is it unlimited, and assuming that it is either one of those leads to some truly horrific coding practices. Better to learn exactly how memory works, and what it's limits are, and learn how to code correctly with those constraints in mind.

Comment: If your function is implemented as truly recursive, then for each recursion your stack will contain data you _do_ need to keep in a stack (parent pointers in tree recursions, for example), but also things like function arguments which either don't change from one call to the next, or which do change but never change back and don't need to be preserved, and local variables which may be the same from one call to the next, and also the hardware stuff:  saved registers and the return address.

Comment: It may be worth noting that the return address is a piece of information more than a mere "hardware implementation artefact".  If you consider a piece of code: `recurse(foo->left); ... recurse(foo->right);`, the return address will be different depending on whether or not you have already visited the left node.  An iterative solution may (depending on algorithm) need to note this explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on the nature of the language and compiler/interpreter.

Some functional languages implement *tail recursion*, for example, to recognize specific cases where the stack frame can be destroyed/freed prior to recursing into the next call. In those special cases among the languages/compilers/interpreters that support it, you can actually have infinite recursion without overflowing the stack.

If you're working with languages that use the hardware stack and don't implement tail recursion, then typically you have to push arguments to the stack prior to branching into a function and pop them off along with return values, so there's somewhat of an implicit data structure there under the hood (if we can call it that). There's all kinds of additional things that can happen here as well, like register shadowing to optimize it.

The hardware stack is usually very efficient, typically just incrementing and decrementing a stack pointer register to push and pop, but it does involve a bit more state and instructions than branching with a loop counter or a condition. Perhaps more importantly, it tends to involve more distant branching to jump into another function's code as opposed to looping within the same body of code which could involve more instruction cache and page misses.

In these types of languages/compilers/interpreters that use the hardware stack and will always overflow it with enough recursion, the loopy routes often provide a performance advantage (but can be more tedious to code).

As a twist, you also have aggressive optimizers sometimes which do all kinds of magic with your code in the process of translating it to machine instructions and linking it like inlining functions and unrolling loops, and when you take all these factors into account, it's often better to just code things a bit more naturally and then measure with a profiler if it could use some tweaking. Of course you shouldn't use recursion in cases that can overflow, but I generally wouldn't worry about the overhead most of the time.